# get_absolute_url very busy database

Tags: python, sql, django, django-debug-toolbar

When I load a product page, I want other products to be offered on that page. But when generating an absolute url for each product, the database is accessed. Accordingly, if there are 10 products on the page, then there will be + 10 calls to the database
How can i reduce the number of queries in the db?
It`s my code:

models.py

```
class Goods(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 related_name='goods',
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                 null=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, verbose_name='название')
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, unique=True, verbose_name='Слаг')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('goods_detail', kwargs={"category_slug[enter image description here][1]": self.category.slug, "goods_slug": self.slug})
```

urls.py

```
path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug:goods_slug>', views.GoodsDetailView.as_view(), name='goods_detail'),
```

views.py

```
class GoodsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Goods
    context_object_name = 'goods'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'goods_slug'
```

goods_detail.html

```
{% for i in  goods.ingredients.all%}<br>
    <a href="{{ i.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ i }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

*The photo shows an example if I display 4 objects on a page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Ingredient has a foreignkey relationship to Goods

In your views.py class you can preload the information by getting additional context (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context)).

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the ingredients related to this object
    context['ingredients'] = Ingredient.objects.filter(goods = self.get_object())
    return context
```

then you can refer to the new context element in your template

```
{% for i in ingredients %}<br>
    <a href="{{ i.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ i }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```